# selecting a node in radTreeView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

hello this is my code and I hope you can help me because telerik support forum sucks

code:

```
  function SearchClick() {

            var search = $get("<%= ApplicationSearchResult.ClientID %>").value;
            var treeView = $find("<%= MainTree.ClientID %>");
            var nodes = treeView.get_allNodes();
            var NextNode = document.getElementById("<%=NextNode.ClientID %>");
            NextNode.style.display = "block";
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                var node = nodes[i];
                if (node.get_text() == search) {
                    node.select();
                    expandAllAncestors(node);
                    return;
                }
            }

         }
```

Markup:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="MainTree" runat="server" CssClass="NewClass" OnNodeClick="NodeClick" 
    Skin="Office2010Silver">
<Nodes>
<telerik:RadTreeNode Selected="true" Text="Hello"  Value="0">
    <Nodes>
        <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Hi" Value="1">
        </telerik:RadTreeNode>
    </Nodes>
    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
<telerik:RadTreeNode  Text="Hellooooooooooooo" Value="2">
    <Nodes>
        <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="helloooo" Value="3">
        </telerik:RadTreeNode>
    </Nodes>
    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
```

```
    <Nodes>
    <telerik:RadTreeNode  Text="Hi" Value="7"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
    <telerik:RadTreeNode  Text="Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" Value="8"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
    <telerik:RadTreeNode  Text="Hello" Value="9"></telerik:RadTreeNode> 
    </Nodes>
    </telerik:RadTreeView>
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="ApplicationSearchResult" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
    <asp:Image src="Magnifier.png" ToolTip="search" onclick="SearchClick();"  style="cursor:pointer;" runat="server" height="17" width="17" ID="Search" />
```

my problem is when node.select() is reached it automatically execute the NodeClick server event how can i prevent this from happening and just when the user click on a node the NodeClick is executed

Comment: see the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607064/node-select-fires-the-node-click-event-in-radtreeview/12607065#12607065

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `node.select();` to `node.set_selected(true)`

Maybe telerik support really sucks but did you tried to read documentation?