# Node.Select() Fires the Node_Click() Event in RadTreeView?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

everytime when you try to call the Node.select() from javascript it will call the aspx.cs event which is Node_Click() which makes alot trouble in code seperation if you wanna make two functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's been like 5 hourse for me trying to figure out the solution for that problem , because each time I try to set the node selected from the javascript side using the following code:

```
var nodes=$find("<%= RadTreeView1.ClientID %>").get_allNodes();
var node1=nodes[0];
node1.Select();
```

//here it calls also the Server event which is the Node_Click() event int the aspx.cs page,

so after a long hard time with that I found out that If you wanna select a node in javascript without firing the event use the following function:

```
node1.set_selected(true);
```

I hope that I could benefit you guys because because I dont want you to spend hours trying
to find this out.

best of luck